# How to view custom option that added programmatically, from the backend

Tags: product, cart, custom-options, backend

I have added custom option programmatically when product adding to the cart. Now I want to know how to view it from the back end after order placed.

Adding the custom option

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$cart =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$param = array(
        'product' => $product->getId(),
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' => array(
            123 => $imagePath  // Custom option with id: 123
        )
    );
    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($param);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $request);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script to get custom options used in order.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
    {
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();
        $customOptions = $options['options'];
        if (!empty($customOptions)) {
            foreach ($customOptions as $option)
            {
                $optionTitle = $option['label'];
                $optionId = $option['option_id'];
                $optionType = $option['type'];
                $optionValue = $option['value'];
            }
        }
    }
```